# Installing ImageMagick on WAMP (Win7) : Class not found

Tags: php, imagemagick, imagick

I've tried just about everything I've been able to find and so far nothing seems to work.

Regardless of what I install, php always returns "Fatal error: Class 'Imagick' not found."

My system is:

- Win7, 64bit
- Apache 2.2.21
- PHP 5.3.10

  - PHP Extension Build: API20090626,TS,VC9

I've installed various versions of ImageMagick (6.6.7, 6.7.1, and 6.8.5, both x86 and x64), and used dll's (VC6 and VC9) from http://chernoivan.ru/tools/imagemagick-dlls.html, http://www.sk89q.com/2010/03/vc6-windows-binaries-for-imagick-2-3-0/, and http://valokuva.org/?m=201211.

WAMP shows the extension as being activated (I added `extension=php_imagick.dll` to my php.ini file)

phpinfo() though never shows anything specific to imagick besides some path variables and the script itself:

```
<?php

header('Content-type: image/jpeg');

$image = new Imagick('image.jpg');

// If 0 is provided as a width or height parameter,
// aspect ratio is maintained
$image->thumbnailImage(100, 0);

echo $image;

?>
```

always says class not found.

What could the problem at this point be?

Answer (score 0):

Discovered the problem.

ImageMagick (at least from what I can tell) will not work on a x64 installation of php.

Fix was to install a different version of WAMP with a x86 build of php.

Used the dll found here: http://www.peewit.fr/imagick/

With ImageMagick-6.8.1-8-Q16-x64-dll.exe found here: http://image_magick.veidrodis.com/image_magick/binaries/